# Git Pull Failed Your local changes would be overwritten

Tags: android, git, github

I want to get the latest update of the project in GitHub and this message shown in android studio

Git Pull Failed Your local changes would be overwritten by merge.
Commit, stash or revert them to proceed

What I did is git -> pull

And actually I do want my files to be overwritten cause we both modified the same file but mine is not correct so I would like to pull my colleague changes. I don't want to commit and push mine since they are wrong.

Any help? I don't use command

Thanks

Comment: First, You need to commit you local changes and after try pull

Comment: if you want to override your local changes see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files

git reset --hard     will delete your local changes
git pull                  will download the new ones

Comment: @Dinesh Thank you so much! I'm a beginner with git it's working!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot solve conflicts after git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538346/cannot-solve-conflicts-after-git-pull)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Your+local+changes+would+be+overwritten+by+merge.+Commit%2C+stash+or+revert+them+to+proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You need to commit your local changes and after try pull